# CIConstantColorGenerator CIFilter failed with error in Playground with Swift 2.0

Tags: swift-playground, cifilter

I tried to create a color filter with the following line of code

```
let parameters = [kCIInputColorKey: CIColor(string: "0.5 0.7 0.3 1.0")]
let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator",    withInputParameters: parameters)
colorFilter?.outputImage
```

but the debug console output the rolling info

```
 <Error>: CGImageProviderCreate: invalid image provider size: 1.79769e+308 x 1.79769e+308.
<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image width.
<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination must have at least one image
CGImageDestinationFinalize failed for output type 'public.tiff'
```

Thanks,
plus: I tried to write this code in Swift Project, it works fine, but when worked in playground, just showed this error

Answer (score 5):

Just try to clarify what size of output image you want to get:
 `colorFilter?.outputImage?.imageByCroppingToRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))`